# Errors in table layout

Tags: tables

I'm trying to have a table by the following code

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|p{3cm}|} \hline
     {\bf Metric} & {\bf Group} & {\bf Formula} \\ \hline
     Sentiment label (SL) & CE & \parbox{3cm}{}Negative(NS) if $txt|txt\in{\rm tc}_i:txt.sent=\ -1$ \newline
     Positive(PS) if $txt|txt\in{\rm tc}_i:txt.sent=\ -1$ \newline
     Neutral(NeutS) if $txt|txt\in{\rm tc}_i:txt.sent=\ -1$ \\ \hline
     Sentiment Ratio (SR) & CE & NSR= $\cfrac{count(NS)}{{tc}_i}$ ,
     PSR = $\cfrac{count(PS)}{{tc}_i}$ ,
     NeutSR =  $\cfrac{count(NeutS)}{{tc}_i}$ \\ \hline
     Brand Trends (BT) & CE &  \parbox{3cm}{ BT =  $\cfrac{{tc}_i}{tc}$} }\\ \hline
     %
    Satisfaction Score (SScore) & CS & \parbox{3cm}{$\forall\ r\ \in\ {\rm rev}_i:\ SScore\ =\ \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{r_j}{n}$} \\ \hline
    %
     Customer Engagement (CE) & CI & \parbox{3cm}{$\forall\ t\ \in\ {\rm tw}_i\ CE\ =\ t.q+t.rt+t.f$ }\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Brand Loyalty metrics}
\label{tab:BLmetrics}
\end{table}
```

at the end, I've got lots of errors and the layout is not so convenient 
[image]

The error is in the third columns

Comment: (1) Please always post full (but minimal) self contained documents, that makes it a lot easier for others to test (2) please cite the explicit error you get (preferably from the log, not the filtered stuff your editor presents)

Comment: remove all the parbox (and also `\bf` and `\rm` should not be used in latex, unless your document was written before 1993)  then set your third column in ragged right using `{|c|c|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|}` (needs array package) then finally remove all the `\ ` from `\forall \ r\  \in` ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, the layout if fixed only using {|c|c|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|}

Answer (score 3):

Rmove all the `\parbox` (and also `\bf` and `\rm` should not be used in latex, unless your document was written before 1993) then set your third column in ragged right using

```
{|c|c|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}|}
```

(needs `array` package) then finally remove all the `\` from `\forall \ r\ \in ...`

Answer (score 1):

As supplement to @David Carlisle answer (+1):

- instead `tabular` is better to use `tabularx` which can exploit whole `\textwidth`
- for the first column is better to use `p` column and with this enable split text in their cells into two (and more) lines. With this more space is left to the last column.
- in cells in the last column is sensible nested `tabular` for describing more option and use `aligned` math environment for multi lines equations.
- in equation I try to correct write all terms, but for some of them is not clear (to me), what they means (are they variables or text)

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{28mm}|c|
                              >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|} 
    \hline
\thead{Metric} &    \thead{Group}   &   \thead{Formula}     \\ 
    \hline
Sentiment Label (SL) & CE &\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} lll@{}}
            Negative(NS)    & if $txt|txt\in \mathrm{tc}_i \mathrm{txt.sent}= -1$   \\                                                       
            Positive(PS)    & if $txt|txt\in\mathrm{tc}_i:\mathrm{txt.sent} = -1$   \\
            Neutral(NeutS)  & if $txt|txt\in\mathrm{tc}_i:\mathrm{txt.sent} = -1$ 
                            \end{tabular}   \\
    \hline
Sentiment Ratio (SR) & CE & $\begin{aligned}[t]
                            \mathrm{NSR}    & = \mathrm{count}(NS){{tc}_i},\\
                            \mathrm{PSR}    & = \dfrac{\mathrm{count(PS)}}{\mathrm{tc}_i},\\
                            \mathrm{NeutSR} &= \dfrac{\mathrm{NeutS}}{\mathrm{tc}_i}
                            \end{aligned} $  \\
    \hline
Brand Trends (BT)   & CE &  $\mathrm{BT} = \dfrac{\mathrm{tc}_i}{\mathrm{tc}}$   \\
    \hline
%
Satisfaction Score (SScore)
                    & CS & $\forall r \in \mathrm{rev}_i: SScore =  \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{r_j}{n}$   \\
    \hline
    %
Customer Engagement (CE) 
                    & CI & $\forall t \in \mathrm{tw}_i\ CE = t.q+t.rt+t.f$   \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Brand Loyalty metrics}
\label{tab:BLmetrics}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]